# Spring-Boot processes HttpServletRequest before registered servlets

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

The following code demonstrates the difference in `HttpServletRequest` processing a request between `Spring-Boot` and a stand-alone servlet container (aka. Tomcat or Jetty). Both work, however I am less than happy with the Spring variant.

I have been unable to create a method to either copy the `InputStream` before it is processed by Spring or to suppress the processing of the request by Spring and just pass it "as is" to the Servlet. The servlet is interacting with a legacy API and needs to read/write bytes directly from the Request Body. Spring tries to map the payload, reads the InputStream and that requires the kludge of reading `ParameterNames` instead of just passing the Request Body on to the underlying socket to the legacy API. Any help turning this horrid spring code into something a bit more sane is greatly appreciated.

Things I've already tried (not necessarily correctly) that haven't worked. Filters to copy the InputStream, various consumes and produces annotations, etc... I also played with `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` to no avail.

The easiest solution in my opinion would be to flag the Servlet that works in `Tomcat` and just have Spring pass on the request via `ServletRegistrationBean` without modification. I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious here.

```
/* 
 * Works in Spring-Boot 1.2.5 
 */
public void doIt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{       
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setContentLength(0);

    Writer w = acquireWriter();

    Enumeration<String> an = request.getParameterNames();

    while(an.hasMoreElements()){
        char[] msg = an.nextElement().toCharArray();
        if(msg[0]=='w')
            continue;
        e.write(msg, 0, msg.length);
    }
}

@Bean
public MyServlet myServlet(){
    return new MyServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
    ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(myServlet(), "/op");
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}

/*
 * Works in Tomcat 7/8 
 */
public void doIt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{       
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setContentLength(0);

    Writer w = acquireWriter();
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");

    char[] buffer = new char[8192];

    int length=-1;
    while((length = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        w.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be me but why do you even have a `@RequestMapping` for this? If this isn't a controller then don't use it. Simply implement the `HttpRequestHandler` interface for this particular piece of functionality, it isn't a controller then don't try to shoehorn it into one.

Comment: I started out that way. I created simple servlet based on the 2nd code snipit. And just registered it using `ServletRegistrationBean`. However Spring continued to attempt to marshal the `HttpServletRequest` payload before handing the request to the servlet via the Dispatcher. That's the real crux of the problem. How do you get Spring to push an `HttpServletRequest` to a registered Servlet without modification.

Comment: If you registered it as a servlet Spring shouldn't get the request anymore. One thing is to make sure that the order of your registration is that it comes before the dispatcher servlet. But regardless of that it should still be able to proces it so there must be something else wrong in your setup. The servlet is simply registered to the embedded tomcat like any other servlet. I also nowhere mentioned a servlet but a `HttpRequestHandler` which is a spring interface!

Comment: I'll checkout the `HttpRequestHandler`. As far as registering the servlet before the dispatcher, I played around with that yesterday and didn't find a good way to do that in Spring-Boot without forgoing most of the auto configuration I like spring-boot for in the first place. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Just set the `order` property of the `ServletRegistrationBean`. It should only be a servlet not a component, controller or whatever. What you have in plain tomcat should simply work without modification (only maybe a change on how to register but that would be it).

Comment: That is exactly my original setup and it does and does not work. The servlet is indeed called, however the `InputStream` of the `HttpServletRequest` is marked at -1 because it has been consumed by another spring component prior to getting passed to servlet. I've re-validated that adding `setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` does not work. In straight tomcat the `InputStream` is untouched and is processed, in spring-boot the `InputStream` is being consumed before being passed to the servlet and the contents marshaled to request parameters.

Comment: This [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856415/write-request-to-file-in-spring-mvc) is also an example of the root issue I am having. How do we get a servlet registered that inst co-opted by the Spring-Boot pluming and passes the request on unaltered to the Servlet as is the incase in a stand along container?

Comment: `do` is a Java keyword and thus introduces a huge red herring in your code snippet.

Comment: The problem is probably not the servlet or its registration, it's the filters that Spring Boot registers, that cause the trouble. Have a look into that.

Comment: afaik there is nothing that consumes the input stream, there might be some filters but those are mainly for setting the charset etc. but they aren't consuming it. At least not to my knowledge. When it is a servlet it is just that and Spring doesn't do anything with it it doesn't even pass through spring (as mentioned maybe some filters). What I also don't get is you are only passing the body not the parameters in your origanal servlet, whereas the working spring solution is about passing the parameters? Basically both are different things...

Comment: To get a feel for what is happening you can put a break point in the servlet and when using Spring (I assume you are using a plain servlet and not something with `@Controller`?!) you can see which filters it passes through.

Comment: I think the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` is the culprit as that is calling `getParameter` which would trigger the preparation of the request. Try registering the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` yourself and bind it to the `DispatcherServlet` only. By default it will be executed for every request. It might be that the same applies to the `CharacterEncodingFilter` as that would read a request header. Use the `Ordered*` variant when registering the filters.

Answer (score 0):

[M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) was right on the money. The problem was the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` calling `getParameter` which triggers the preparation of the request and reads the `InputStream`. I played around with registering the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` and a `DispatcherServlet`, but found it cleaner and easier to just override the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, but both solutions do work. Here is exactly what I did to pass the request unaltered to the servlet.

```
@Bean
public HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter(){
    return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(){
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            if("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/op")) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
            }
        }
    };
}
```